# How to serve different contents based on the browser

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I recently stumbled across this website: [**LocalMapsAccess**](http://localmapsaccess.com/), where, when I open the site with Chrome, in the footer I could see this image:

[image: Chrome Footer]

And in the Firefox, the same website shows a different content:

[image: Firefox Footer]

I want to implement this, but I am clueless what should I do or how do I start with. Can someone please help me on this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: After seeing the code of the site, it looks like they are using some kind of browser sniffing method. This can be done by getting the User Agent String of the client. This is a poor method, but mostly works, as User Agent can be **easily forged**.

Comment: Use `navigator` object from BOM.

Comment: Browser Object Model? Byte-Order Mark? `:P`

Comment: Can you please explain?

Comment: @nandhakumar Sure, writing an answer for you... `:)` Is PHP solution okay for you?

Comment: Close as Typo? Wow! Who did that? LoL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After seeing the code of the site, it looks like they are using some kind of browser sniffing method. This can be done by getting the User Agent String of the client. This is a poor method, but mostly works, as User Agent can be **easily forged**.

Okay for you, the solution is:

1. **Server Side** using PHP.
   You need to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`.
2. **Client Side** using JavaScript.
   You need to use `navigator.userAgent`.

**Solution using PHP**

If you see the [`get_browser()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) manual in PHP Documentation, there's a comment by [`ruudrp at live dot nl`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php#101125) five years ago.

If you put this code in PHP:

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/plain");
    function getBrowser() 
    { 
        $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
        $bname = 'Unknown';
        $platform = 'Unknown';
        $version= "";

        //First get the platform?
        if (preg_match('/linux/i', $u_agent)) {
            $platform = 'linux';
        }
        elseif (preg_match('/macintosh|mac os x/i', $u_agent)) {
            $platform = 'mac';
        }
        elseif (preg_match('/windows|win32/i', $u_agent)) {
            $platform = 'windows';
        }

        // Next get the name of the useragent yes seperately and for good reason
        if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent) && !preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent)) 
        { 
            $bname = 'Internet Explorer'; 
            $ub = "MSIE"; 
        } 
        elseif(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$u_agent)) 
        { 
            $bname = 'Mozilla Firefox'; 
            $ub = "Firefox"; 
        } 
        elseif(preg_match('/Chrome/i',$u_agent)) 
        { 
            $bname = 'Google Chrome'; 
            $ub = "Chrome"; 
        } 
        elseif(preg_match('/Safari/i',$u_agent)) 
        { 
            $bname = 'Apple Safari'; 
            $ub = "Safari"; 
        } 
        elseif(preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent)) 
        { 
            $bname = 'Opera'; 
            $ub = "Opera"; 
        } 
        elseif(preg_match('/Netscape/i',$u_agent)) 
        { 
            $bname = 'Netscape'; 
            $ub = "Netscape"; 
        } 

        // finally get the correct version number
        $known = array('Version', $ub, 'other');
        $pattern = '#(?<browser>' . join('|', $known) .
        ')[/ ]+(?<version>[0-9.|a-zA-Z.]*)#';
        if (!preg_match_all($pattern, $u_agent, $matches)) {
            // we have no matching number just continue
        }

        // see how many we have
        $i = count($matches['browser']);
        if ($i != 1) {
            //we will have two since we are not using 'other' argument yet
            //see if version is before or after the name
            if (strripos($u_agent,"Version") < strripos($u_agent,$ub)){
                $version= $matches['version'][0];
            }
            else {
                $version= $matches['version'][1];
            }
        }
        else {
            $version= $matches['version'][0];
        }

        // check if we have a number
        if ($version==null || $version=="") {$version="?";}

        return array(
            'userAgent' => $u_agent,
            'name'      => $bname,
            'version'   => $version,
            'platform'  => $platform,
            'pattern'    => $pattern
        );
    } 

    // now try it
    $ua = getBrowser();
    $yourbrowser = "Your browser: " . $ua['name'] . " " . $ua['version'] . " on " .$ua['platform'] . " reports:\n" . $ua['userAgent'];
    print_r($yourbrowser);
?>
```

I am just trying to add the code here. Kindly behold, but this **should be the answer**.

---

**Update:** PHP Code output.

You would get the following:

1. **Chrome Browser**

   ```
   Your browser: Google Chrome 47.0.2526.111 on windows reports:
   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.111 Safari/537.36
   ```
2. **Firefox Browser**

   ```
   Your browser: Mozilla Firefox 42.0 on windows reports:
   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:42.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/42.0
   ```
3. **Internet Explorer**

   ```
   Your browser: Unknown ? on windows reports:
   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; managedpc; rv:11.0) like Gecko
   ```

Okay, the above code doesn't work in **Internet Explorer 11** on **Windows 7**. Anyway, who cares about IE now-a-days.

---

**Final Update**

Now based on the above code, you can check this way to deliver different contents across different browsers from your server side.

```
<?php
    // The same function to be called.
    $ua = getBrowser();
    // Let's check for our required values.
    if ($ua['name'] == "Mozilla Firefox")
        // Add Firefox's content.
        echo "firefox.png";
    elseif ($ua['name'] == "Google Chrome")
        // Add Chrome's content.
        echo "chrome.png";
    else
        // Finally add our devastated IE's content.
        echo "ie.png";
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, I am using PHP only. PHP Solution would be great.

Comment: @nandhakumar Yeah, that's the code. The final one. Check it out.

Comment: Okay this looks promising. Let me try and come back.

Comment: @nandhakumar Sure I am waiting for it. `:)`